# Doctrine, remove collection?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to remove a collection with Doctrine with Symfony2.

So, i retrieve all objects like that :

```
$comments = $em->getRepository('ProjectApplicationBundle:Comment')->findBy(array('user_id' => $user_id));
```

So, with this, i can retrieve a lots of comments.

How can i remove these comments ? A simple `$em->remove($comments)` don't work.

A need to loop comments and remove each element ? It is better to write the query directly ?
Any better ways ? Thanks

Comment: Did you not forget `$em->flush();` ?

Comment: No, we can't remove a collection with remove()

Comment: In this case `foreach` will help you, to each loop you remove an element from the collection

Answer (score 8):

You need to put them in loop and remove each one

```
foreach ($comments as $cm) {
    $em->remove($cm);
}
$em->flush();
```

Just in case for future if you have OneToMany relation for a field and you want to remove all related objects to this or a specific object in the collection you can try

```
//entity class
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Target_Entity_Class",mappedBy="mapped_property")
 * @var ArrayCollection
 */
$objects;
//...
public function removeObject(\Name\Space\To\Target\Entity $target)
{
    $this->objects->removeElement($target);
}
```

And in your controller you can say

```
// assume $removed_objects_list is an array of related objects which you want to remove
$target_object = $em->getRepository('TargetEntity')->find($target_id);
foreach ($removed_objects_list as $object) {
    $target_object->removeObject($object);
}
$em->flush();
```

Comment: The first one will fix your issue. Then next one is a sample which might be useful for future

Comment: And it's not better to write the delete query directly ?

Comment: What do you mean by *directly* ? Do mean `$em->remove($comments)` ?

Comment: It's not better to write the delete query with createquerybuilder for example ? Is it not speeder than a loop, remove and flush ?

Comment: Might be a tiny bit faster to use sql but hardly noticeable.  Just let the ORM do it's job.  If you are removing the comments because you are removing the user then just add a cascade option on the relation and the comments will automatically be deleted.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Base on the documentation **The actual DELETE query, however, isn't actually executed until the flush() method is called.** `remove` does not fire until you `flush` them and I think Symfony will make it one query to be executed. On the other hand you can build it by `createQueryBuilder` which is one query to be fired. I suggest to check symfony profiler while running each command and see how many transaction happened.

Comment: Doesn't `foreach ($collection as $el) { ...->removeElement($el); }` does exactly what `$collection->clear()`? AFAICS `remove()` does `unset()` whether `clear()` just assigns empty array to the collection.

Answer (score 4):

One-liner should be like this:

```
$comments->forAll(function($key, $entity) { 
    $this->em->remove($entity); 
    return true; 
});
```

Rest is good!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner:

```php
$comments->forAll(function($key, $entity) {$this->em->remove($entity); return true;});
```

Of course, don't forget the `$em->flush();` afterwards.

Comment: This one-liner does not work, because if you don't return anything *truthy* from the callback, the `forAll` stops after the first element.

Comment: @fracz Thanks! Corrected